# Convergence proof of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $a_n$ be the sequence given by:

• $a_n =5$ if $n$ is even, $a_n=5−\frac 1n$ if $n$ is odd.

Suppose $d$ is a distance on $\Bbb R$ s.t $\{5\}$ is open. Prove that $a_n$ converges with the distance $d$, if it converges. Provide the limit if it converges.

How would you go on proving this?

Comment: I suppose that by $d$ is a distance on $\mathbb R$ such that $\{5\}$ is open you mean that a metric topology is defined that puts $5$ at a positive distance from all other real numbers.  This makes it pretty difficult for a sequence $a_n$ to converge to $5$.  Since this is not the usual topology on the real numbers, thinking about Cauchy sequences may be throwing you off the trail.

Comment: how would you go on proving this? @hardmath

Comment: Your wording of the question seems slightly ambiguous.  I think a reasonable problem would be (1) If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges in the metric topology $(\mathbb R, d)$, prove that it does.  (2) If the sequence converges, provide its limit.  As I previously pointed out, the nature of the metric (distance) $d$ makes it *difficult* for a sequence to converge to $5$.

Comment: I'm perplexed a bit by a sequence converging if it converges.  Of course it converges if it converges.  If you mean if it converges for the eclidean distance ... well that doesn't need to be stated as it clearly does.

Comment: Oh, I see.  We must first determine if it *does* converge.  Then if it converges, prove it.  Well, maybe we should consider that maybe it doesn't converge.

Answer (score 4):

In the unusual topology provided by metric $d$ (we are told), the singleton set $\{5\}$ is an open set.

Now the subsequence $\{a_{2n}\}$ of even terms is identically $5$, and this subsequence does indeed converge to $5$.

But the odd terms $\{a_{2n+1}\}$ never reach the open neighborhood $\{5\}$, much less remain inside after some finite number of terms.

Therefore the sequence $\{a_n\}$ as a whole does not have a limit and does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

$\{5\}$ is open.  That means there is a positive $\epsilon $ in which $5$ is the only number within $\epsilon $ of $5$.

If {$a_n$} converges to $x $ then for $\epsilon/2$ there is a $N $ such that for $n, m > N; n$ even and $m$ odd than $d (x, a_n) = d (x,5)$ and $d (x,a_m) = d (x,5 - 1/m) $ are less than $\epsilon/2$.

Then by triangle inequality $d (x,5) \le d (x,a_n)+d (x,a_m)< \epsilon$ which is only possible if $x=5$, which is impossible as $d (5,a_m) > \epsilon $.

So $\{a_n\}$ can't converge.